# Concavity of entropy difference

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, convex-analysis, entropy

Suppose that $\mathrm{A}$ is a $n\times n$ random matrix with a given distribution. Suppose that $\mathrm{U}$ is a diagonal unitary random matrix, defined as
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
\exp(i\theta_1)&0&\cdots&0\\
0&\exp(i\theta_2)&\cdots&0\\
0&0&\ddots&0\\
0&0&\cdots&\exp(i\theta_n)
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $\theta_i$ are i.i.d. Uniform random variable over $[0,2\pi]$, independent of $\mathrm{A}$, and $i$ is the imaginary number.

I need to show that the following function is **concave** w.r.t. the input distribution:
\begin{align*}
F(p(\mathbf{x}))\triangleq H(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X})- H(\mathrm{A} \mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}),
\end{align*}
where $\mathbf{X}$ is a continuous random vector of size $n$, with probability distribution $p(\mathbf{x})$, and $H(\cdot)$ is the Shannon entropy. This means that we need to show that for any $0 \leq \lambda \leq 1$, $p_1(\mathbf{x})$ and $p_2(\mathbf{x})$
\begin{align*}
\lambda F(p_1(\mathbf{x}))+ (1-\lambda) F(p_2(\mathbf{x})) \leq  F(p(\mathbf{x})),
\end{align*}
where $p(\mathbf{x})=\lambda p_1(\mathbf{x})+ (1-\lambda) p_2(\mathbf{x}) $.

P.S. Some extra assumptions on $\mathrm{A}$ might be needed.

Comment: I don't understand your (interesting) question. Please clarify your notation: What does "concave r.r.t. the input distribution" mean? concave w.r.t. $p$ (the notation $p(x)$in this context does not make much sense) or w,r,t, $X$ or ...?

Comment: The entropy function (and hence the defined $F$ function), is a function of the underlying probability distribution, and not $\mathbf{X}$. I wrote it down. Please let me know if I'm not clear.

Comment: Now this is clear!

Comment: What happens in the situation when all distributions are discrete (with the diagonal entries, for instance, taking iid values +1 and -1), and one deals with the usual entropy instead of the differential one?

Comment: Still I don't know the answer. I'll think about it.

Comment: Are the entries of $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathbf{X}$ real-valued?

Comment: No, they can have complex values.

Comment: Is $\mathbf{X}$ independent of $\mathrm{A}$ and $\mathrm{U}$?

Comment: Yes, it's independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further assumptions, I think $F$ is not necessarily concave.

Let $\mathbf{X}_1\sim p_1$, $\mathbf{X}_2\sim p_2$ and $B\sim\textrm{Bernoulli}(\lambda)$ be independent, and let
\begin{align*}
   \mathbf{X} &:=
      \begin{cases}
         \mathbf{X}_1 & \text{if $B=1$,} \\
         \mathbf{X}_2 & \text{if $B=0$.}
      \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Then, $\mathbf{X}\sim p=\lambda p_1 + (1-\lambda) p_2$.

In general, for two random variables $Z$ and $C$, where $Z$ is continuous and $C$ is discrete, we have
\begin{align*}
   h(Z) + H(C\,|\,Z) &= H(C) + h(Z\,|\,C) \;,
\end{align*}
where $H(\cdot)$ denotes the ordinary (discrete) entropy and $h(\cdot)$ is the differential entropy.

It follows that
\begin{align*}
   &
   \overbrace{h(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}) - h(\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X})}^{F(p)}
      +
      \overbrace{H(B\,|\,\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X})
      - H(B\,|\,\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X})}^{\displaystyle(\sharp)} \\
   &=
      h(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}\,|\,B)
      - h(\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}\,|\,B)
      + H(B) - H(B) \\
   &=
      \lambda\big(\underbrace{h(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_1) - h(\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}_1)}_{F(p_1)}\big)
      +
      (1-\lambda)\big(\underbrace{h(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_2) - h(\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}_2)}_{F(p_2)}\big)
\end{align*}
*provided* that $p_1$ and $p_2$ are absolutely continuous w.r.t. the three-dimensional Lebesgue and $\mathrm{A}$ is almost surely non-singular.  (Otherwise, the differential entropies become $-\infty$ and $F$ would not be well-defined.)

Therefore, in order for $F$ to be concave, we must have
\begin{align*}
   (\sharp) = H(B\,|\,\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X})
      - H(B\,|\,\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X})
   &\leq 0 \tag{?}
\end{align*}
*whenever* $p_1$ and $p_2$ are absolutely continuous and $\mathrm{A}$ is almost surely non-singular.

[**Update**: The original example was not valid because it disregarded the requirement that $p_1$ and $p_2$ have to be absolutely continuous and $\mathrm{A}$ non-singular.  The following sketch is meant to circumvent that issue.]

Fix $0<\lambda<1$.  Let
\begin{align*}
   \hat{\mathrm{A}} &:=
      \begin{bmatrix}
         1 & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
         0 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
         0 & -1/2 & 1/2
      \end{bmatrix}
   &
   \hat{\mathbf{X}}_1 &:=
      \begin{bmatrix}
         1 \\ 0 \\ 0
      \end{bmatrix}
    &
   \hat{\mathbf{X}}_2 &:=
      \begin{bmatrix}
         0 \\ 1 \\ 1
      \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
Let $\mathrm{A}$ be a non-singular (deterministic or random) matrix which is very close to $\hat{\mathrm{A}}$, and let $\mathbf{X}_1=\hat{\mathbf{X}}+\sigma\mathbf{Z}_1$ and $\mathbf{X}_2=\hat{\mathbf{X}}+\sigma\mathbf{Z}_2$, where $\mathbf{Z}_1$ and $\mathbf{Z}_2$ are two independent standard normal vectors and $\sigma$ is very small.  Assume that $\mathbf{Z}_1$, $\mathbf{Z}_2$, $\mathrm{U}$ and $\mathrm{A}$ are all independent.

Note that both $\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_2$ are highly concentrated around a vector very close to $\hat{\mathbf{X}}_1$.  By chooseing $\mathrm{A}$ close enough to $\hat{\mathrm{A}}$, we can make sure that $\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_2$ are hardly distinguishable.  Hence, $\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}$ would hardly have any information about $B$, and as a result
\begin{align*}
   H(B\,|\,\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}) &\approx H(B) = H(\lambda) \;.
\end{align*}

On the other hand, $\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}_1$ and $\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}_2$ will be distinguishable, with $\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}_1$ still being close to the linear span of $\hat{\mathbf{X}}_1$ and $\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}_2$ typically far from it.  In particular, $\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}$ has significant information about $B$ and hence
\begin{align*}
   H(B\,|\,\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X}) &\ll H(B) = H(\lambda) \;.
\end{align*}
Therefore, in this example, $(\sharp)>0$ contrary to the claim.

Comment: For deterministic invertible matrices $\mathrm{A}$, the result is correct. I guess, I should have stated the invertible condition for $\mathrm{A}$.

Comment: Is $F(p)$ really concave when $\mathrm{A}$ is deterministic and invertible?  Isn't $F(p)$ continuous as a function of $\mathrm{A}$?  If so, we can choose $\mathrm{A}$ invertible but very close to the matrix I used above, and the concavity inequality would still fail.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I argue as following: Let $\mathbf{Y}=(|X_1|,|X_2|,\cdots,|X_n|)$ and $\mathbf{Z}=(\angle X_1,\angle X_2 ,\cdots,\angle X_n)$. We have $h(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X})=h(\mathbf{X})+\log(|det(\mathrm{A})|)$. Hence $F(P)=h(\mathbf{X})-h(\mathrm{U} \mathbf{X})=h(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{Y})-2n\pi$, and we know that entropy is a concave function. Note that in the last step, I changed the coordinate from Cartersian to polar.

Comment: In fact, $F(p)$ is not continuous w.r.t $\mathrm{A}$, since $\log$ is not continuous around 0.

Comment: I am not used to differential entropy, so I don't get how you did your last step.  Regarding the (dis-)continuity of $F(p)$, we are not applying $\log$ around $0$ in $h(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X})$ as long as $\mathbf{X}$ is absolutely continuous, are we?

Comment: I think there is a bug in my example.  The example does provide a case in which $(\sharp)>0$.  However in this case, the distribution of the vectors $\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_1$, $\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X}_2$, etc. are not absolutely continuous with respect to the 3d Lebesgue, hence the differential entropies are $-\infty$ and $F(p)$ is not well-defined.

Comment: However, I still think that it can be fixed by an approximation argument.  I'll try to fix it.

Comment: To see the discontinuity of $F(P)$, note that due to the relation $h(\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X})=h(\mathbf{X})+\log(|det(\mathrm{A})|)$, whenever $\mathrm{A}$ is deterministic and invertible, $F(P)=h(\mathbf{X})-h(U\mathbf{X})$ does not depend on $\mathrm{A}$, while when $det(\mathrm{A})=0$, this does not hold.

Comment: This means that we should have $H(B|\mathrm{A}\mathbf{X})-H(B|\mathrm{A}\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X})=H(B|\mathbf{X})-H(B|\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X})$. However, both terms in $H(B|\mathbf{X})-H(B|\mathrm{U}\mathbf{X})$ are very small, while as you have argued, the differnce is not small.

Comment: How do you prove the below claim?

\begin{align*}
   h(Z) + H(C\,|\,Z) &= H(C) + h(Z\,|\,C) \;,
\end{align*}

Comment: The joint distribution of $Z$ and $C$ can be described by a function $f(z,c)$ where $f_Z(z):=\sum_c f(z,c)$ is the probability density function of $Z$ and $p_C(c):=\int_z f(z,c)\mathrm{d}z$ is the probability mass function of $C$.  Now, the quantity $-\sum_c\int_z f(z,c)\log f(z,c)\mathrm{d}z$ can be decomposed in two ways, by either writing $f(z,c)=f_Z(z)p_C(c\,|\,Z=z)$ or $f(z,c)=p_C(c)f_Z(z\,|\,C=c)$, where $p_C(c\,|\,Z=z)$ is the conditional mass of $C$ given $Z$, and $f_Z(z\,|\,C=c)$ is the conditional density of $Z$ given $C$.  These two decompositions give the two sides of the equality.

Comment: Thanks. How do you define $p_{C}(C|Z=z)$? Is it like $\frac{f(z,c)}{f_Z(z)}$?

Comment: Yes!  More precisely, for a fixed $c$, $p_C(c\,|\,Z)=\mathbb{P}(C=c\,|\,Z)$ is the conditional probability of the event $\{C=c\}$ given a continuous random variable $Z$, so it is only almost surely defined.  The ratio $f(Z,c)/f_Z(Z)$ is a version of that conditional probability.